# How to use HikariCP dataSourceClassName with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift, hikaricp

I am trying to write an application that uses HikariCP for its pooling.
(BTW, I am using Redshift and its [JDBC driver](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-jdbc-driver) which AFAI checked is almost a copy-paste of [pgjdbc](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc)).

I can use `jdbcUrl` and get some results:

```
private static void initRedshiftDataSource()
{
    ds = new RedshiftDataSource(); // this is just a wrapper around HikaricpDataSource
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
    ds.setMinimumIdle(2);
    ds.setIdleTimeout(45);
    ds.setJdbcUrl(Jdbc_URL);
    ds.setUsername(Username);
    ds.setPassword(Password);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("LogPath", LogPath);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("DSILogLevel", DSILogLevel);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("IDP_TENANT", "idp_tenant");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("ssl", "false");
}
```

But if I try to set PostgreSQL `dataSourceClassName` from [popular-datasource-class-names table](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names):

```
private static void initRedshiftDataSource()
{
    ds = new RedshiftDataSource();  // this is just a wrapper around HikaricpDataSource
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.amazon.redshift.ds.RedshiftSimpleDataSource");
    ds.setAutoCommit(true);
    ds.setUsername(Username);
    ds.setPassword(Password);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "dev");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", "5432");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("DSILogLevel", DSILogLevel);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("LogPath", LogPath);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("IDP_TENANT", "idp_tenant");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("ssl", "false");
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Property DSILogLevel does not exist on target class com.amazon.redshift.ds.RedshiftSimpleDataSource
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:135)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:59)
        at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:54)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:328)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:114)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at com.amazon.redshift.ds.RedshiftDataSource2.getConnection(RedshiftDataSource2.java:1695)
```

Which is kinda obvious as pgjdbc's `BaseDataSource` doesn't have my custom properties.

**Also:**

Even if I comment out my custom properties to see what happens, I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
        at com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException.getSQLException(RedshiftException.java:56)
        at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:339)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at com.amazon.redshift.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:100)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at com.amazon.redshift.ds.RedshiftDataSource2.getConnection(RedshiftDataSource2.java:1695)
```

It contacts `DriverManager.getConnection` which I don't think is what HikariCP wants.

So, I am confused.

Is the premise of HikariCP for popular databases is unverified and pgjdbc does not support connection pooling? Has anybody tried pgjdbc and HikariCP this way?

Or its the Redshift JDBC driver which might have trouble somewhere?

Comment: _"Is the premise of HikariCP for popular databases is unverified and pgjdbc does not support connection pooling?"_ No, HikariCP provides the connection pooling, that has nothing to do with with the underlying driver used. But is not clear to me what that `RedShiftDataSource` is you're using. You say it is "just a wrapper around HikaricpDataSource", but that is insufficient information. Also, it is not HikariCP that calls `DriverManager`, it is `com.amazon.redshift.ds.common.BaseDataSource` which is a superclass of `com.amazon.redshift.ds.RedshiftSimpleDataSource`.

Comment: In other words, HikariCP tries to use `RedshiftSimpleDataSource` as you configured, and that then fails to create a connection for unclear reasons (or you left that out of your stacktrace).

Comment: As an aside, referring to the Redshift driver as "pgjdbc" in your question is slightly confusing, although the Redshift driver is - I guess - a fork of pgjdbc, it is **not** pgjdbc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel HikariCP says we should use `PGSimpleDataSource` which is derived from `BaseDataSource`. So, I meant to say HikarCP.getConnection will 'subsequently' result in invoking `DriverManager.getConnection`, clearly due to our DataSourceClassName setting instructed by HikariCP. That's my confusion. I know HikariCP is not responsible for pgjdbc internals but there must have been a reason it instructed what to put in DataSourceClassName. Had they tested this? How did they warn about mysql's settings being broken but didn't warn on pgjdbc which is widely used? I can't find answer to this.

Comment: About wrapper. Let's say it is as simple as :
class  RedShiftDataSource extends HikaricpDataSource {}
(and the constructors ofcourse)

Comment: Maybe I have to install&test pgresql and pgjdbc to remove the redshift/pg confusion. Although I have very strong opinion that they are same in that part.

Comment: You need to set the `dataSourceClassName` so HikariCP know which data source to use to create connections. HikariCP then puts those connections in the connection pool it manages. The fact PostgreSQL and subsequently Redshift decided to implement those data sources by calling `DriverManager.getConnection` is not a concern for HikariCP, and it is not even related to the problem you're having. You're focusing on the wrong thing here. The problem is that `com.amazon.redshift.Driver#connect` throws an exception, you need to fix that (likely the cause is further down the exception stacktrace).

Comment: Yes @MarkRotteveel. In the `DataSourceClassName` case I really put server name to begin with `xxx` :|. So that is fixed, thanks to your hint to divert my focus. I can see it goes through Driver manager, and attempting to create 3 creations, results in 10 connection which is Hikari's fixed pool size.
Now I will go see what I can do with extra parameters which are unknown to `BaseDataSource`.
Thanks